# Having trouble understanding multidimensional arrays in as3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have some code like:

```
private function makeGrid():void
    {
        _grid = new Array();

        for(var i:int = 0; i < stage.stageWidth / GRID_SIZE; i++)
        {
            _grid[i] = new Array();

            for(var j:int = 0; j < stage.stageHeight / GRID_SIZE; j++)
            {
                _grid[i][j] = new Array();
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't quite understand what's going on. I get that in the first for loop it determines the number of columns needed, and in the second it determines rows, but I don't get why I'm making arrays out of `_grid[i]` and `_grid[i][j]`.

For instance, `_grid[i] = new Array();` get's called 16 times (800px/50px), so that would make 16 arrays right? Why do I need those if the second for loops is already calculating the amount of rows I need?

Comment: With the code you provided, you're creating a three-dimensional array for what I assume is a two-dimensional grid. The _grid = new Array() declaration sets the array for your columns. The _grid[i] sets a row array for each column `i`. The last one, however, _grid[i][j] would create a THIRD array for each row in each column. See it as the Z axis, or depth.

Comment: That make sense, this is coming from a tutorial on making ai move across a grid. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to elaborate on what has already been commented. Let's say that you are creating a 2D grid formed of rows and columns and you wanted to store some sort of data at each "cell" or specified index of the grid.

The first step is to create the first array to hold either the rows or columns (which you choose first doesn't really matter as you can adjust the `for` loops either way).

The first `for` loop creates a new row, then in the next inner loop you fill all the columns of that row (if we had chosen columns to be created first then we would fill all the rows of the columns). In this case the inner loop is creating all the columns with another array (making it a 3-dimensional array as mentioned in the comments).

The reason for doing this is for organization and easy look up. If you wanted to see the data stored in the 1st column of the 3rd row it would be as easy as doing `_gird[2][0]`.

Now as to why a 3rd dimension is made as in `_grid[i][j] = new Array();` that is specific to what kind of data needs to be stored at that row and column.

Comment: Thank you! That helps a lot, and in the tutorial, the data being stored in _grid[i][j] is a ball that's going to roll around on the grid.

Comment: In your code, it's not a ball, but an Array. `_grid[i][j] = new Array()`. This is what makes it a 3-dimensional Array. The first dimension is the outer array. The second dimension is _grid[I], which contains an Array. At each j in _grid[I], you're adding yet another array.